# Highcharts (changing dimensions of columnrange chart with live data)

Tags: xml, highcharts

I have created several charts with Highcharts (gauge, column, line). For some reason, I am unable to get my columnrange chart to update the range of the series based on input from an live XML feed. No problem with the other chart types.

I've tried dozens of things, stuck with something like:
chart.series[0].points[0].update(newVal4);

Whats the command to change the lower and upper bounds of a columnrange chart using live data?

Site of interest: http://www.rogowx.org/wxstation/boxplot.html

Thanks!

Comment: What "newVal4" variable does contain ?

Comment: newVal4 is data from an XML file. It will contain a Float number such as 29.9. This value updates when the XML files updates. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at example, http://jsfiddle.net/YdHxm/2/ so only whay you need is add ajax call and get XML values.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        chart.series[0].data[0].update([-5,20]);
    });
```